# With MVC5 and Unobtrusive Validation how do I add a custom html attribute to each validation message's individual span?

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation

When using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` it renders an outer span, which I can set html attributes on ... but when there are error messages it renders a new span inside this for each validation message.

I'd like to be able to specifiy HTML attributes for the inner spans.

```html
    You must enter your name.

I want to be able to add the attribute `data-glyph="circle-x"` to the span with `id="Name-error"`.

Is this possible?  How do I do it?

Comment: You cant, unless you modify the `jquery.validate.js` file (the `.showLabel()` function in that file creates the inner span element)

Comment: Thats anoying... I was hoping for a way to do this that didn't involve hacking vendor files